I use java ee how to update
I am building a web application using Java where I manage entities related to invoices, doctors (Bacsi), and patients (Benhnhan). The issue occurs when I try to update the fields for doctors and patients through a combobox.
Even though I call the AddOrUpdate method, the update doesn't work as expected for Bacsi and Benhnhan. There are no errors during execution, but the updated values for the combobox fields are not saved in the database. I also tried using update instead of saveOrUpdate in my repository, but it didn’t fix the problem.
Here is my code for the repository, service, and servlet layers.
Repository Layer:
This method handles the saveOrUpdate logic for the HoaDonEntity:
public void addOrUpdate(HoaDonEntity hoaDon) {
    try {
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.saveOrUpdate(hoaDon);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Service Layer:
The interface defines the methods, and the implementation handles the conversion logic for the HoaDonRequest to HoaDonEntity:
public class HoaDonIplm implements Icomon<HoaDonResponse, HoaDonRequest> {
    @Override
    public void AddOrUpdate(HoaDonRequest object) {
        hoaDonReponsitory.addOrUpdate(converHoaDonFromRequest(object));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public HoaDonEntity converHoaDonFromRequest(HoaDonRequest hoaDonRequest) {
        HoaDonEntity hoaDon = new HoaDonEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(hoaDon, hoaDonRequest);

        if (hoaDonRequest.getMaBn() != null) {
            BenhNhanEntity benhNhan = new BenhNhanRepository().getOne(hoaDonRequest.getMaBn());
            hoaDon.setBenhNhan(benhNhan);
        }
        if (hoaDonRequest.getMaBs() != null) {
            BacSiEntity bacSi = new BacSiRepository().getOne(hoaDonRequest.getMaBs());
            hoaDon.setBacSi(bacSi);
        }
        return hoaDon;
    }
}

Servlet Layer:
Here is how the doPost method handles the update requests:
@SneakyThrows
private void Update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HoaDonEntity hoaDon = new HoaDonEntity();
    String maHd = request.getParameter("maHd");
    HoaDonResponse hoaDonResponse = hoaDonIplm.getOne(maHd);

    BeanUtils.populate(hoaDonResponse, request.getParameterMap());
    BenhNhanEntity benhNhan = new BenhNhanRepository().getOne(hoaDonResponse.getMaBn());
    BacSiEntity bacSi = new BacSiRepository().getOne(hoaDonResponse.getMaBs());
    hoaDonResponse.setTenBn(benhNhan.getTenBn());
    hoaDonResponse.setTenBs(bacSi.getTenBs());
    hoaDonIplm.AddOrUpdate(hoaDonResponse);
    load(request, response);
}


Fix your formatting.

You will get better reactions here if you (a) provide [MCVE],  (b) carefully craft a very specific narrowly-focused technical question, and (c) translate all the pieces to English.
